# SQL SELECT only when all items match

Tags: sql, database

So I have 2 tables:

```
Courses:
-course_ID (primary key)
-course_code
-title

Sections:
-section_ID (primary key)
-course_ID (foreign key)
-day
```

Each course has a number of sections that belong to it. Let's use an example.

The tables:

```
course_ID    course_code    title
1            ABC            Title1
2            BBC            Title2 

section_ID    course_ID    day
1             1            Monday
2             1            Tuesday
3             2            Monday
4             2            Monday
```

I want to be able to run a query that asks for all courses that give me ONLY the ones where all of their sections fit a certain criteria. So in this case, let's say I want to see "All the courses which have ALL of their sections on Monday". The desired output would be:

```
course_ID    course_code    title    section_ID    day
2            BBC            Title2   3             Monday
2            BBC            Title2   4             Monday
```

Notice how the entry (2, ABC, Title1, 1, Monday) is omitted? I can't seem to think of a way to do this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: what have you done so far? - also, if homework, you should specify that in the tags...

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT  *
  FROM courses c1
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1
      FROM  sections c2
      WHERE c1.course_id = c2.course_id
       AND  c2.day <> 'Monday' 
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM Courses WHERE course_ID NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT course_ID FROM Sections WHERE day != 'Monday')
```

Comment: If you vote down, would you mind leaving a comment explaining why? The query will give him results he wants^^

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps select courses where not exists (all sections except the sections that satisfy your criteria)?

Comment: I can help with syntax, too, if you need. This is a subquery-based solution using set difference and NOT EXISTS.

Comment: Two words: [antijoin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra#Antijoin_.28.E2.96.B7.29) ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT c.*
FROM Courses c
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM 
                  Sections s
                  WHERE Day <> Monday
                  and s.CourseID = c.CourseID)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from Sections s1 
   where not exists (
       select 1 from Sections s2 
           where s1.course_ID = s2.course_ID and s1.day <> s2.day)
```

It's saying to pull all sections where a record under the same course doesn't have a different day.  That means you get single records as well as multiple records, so long as the days are the same.

Answer (score 0):

You should select all the sections with day = 'Monday' and from that result, it's easy to join with the Courses table to get the courses.

```
select distinct c.course_id
    from Courses c
        inner join Sections s on s.course_id = c.course_id
    where s.day = 'Monday';
```